# Creating a .wav File in C#

Tags: c#, wav

As an excuse to learn C#, I have been trying to code a simple project: creating audio files. To start, I want to make sure that I can write files that meet the WAVE format. I have researched the format online (for example, [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)), but whenever I try to play back a file, it won't open correctly. Here is my code. Is something missing or incorrect?

```
uint numsamples = 44100;
ushort numchannels = 1;
ushort samplelength = 1; // in bytes
uint samplerate = 22050;

FileStream f = new FileStream("a.wav", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(f);

wr.Write("RIFF");
wr.Write(36 + numsamples * numchannels * samplelength);
wr.Write("WAVEfmt ");
wr.Write(16);
wr.Write((ushort)1);
wr.Write(numchannels);
wr.Write(samplerate);
wr.Write(samplerate * samplelength * numchannels);
wr.Write(samplelength * numchannels);
wr.Write((ushort)(8 * samplelength));
wr.Write("data");
wr.Write(numsamples * samplelength);

// for now, just a square wave
Waveform a = new Waveform(440, 50);

double t = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < numsamples; i++, t += 1.0 / samplerate)
{
    wr.Write((byte)((a.sample(t) + (samplelength == 1 ? 128 : 0)) & 0xff));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'it won't open correctly'? Please mention the exact error or exception.

Comment: The code above produces this error message when I try to play it: "Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."

But then I changed the text output to write each char individually (I guess as a string, they put the null terminators in, which screws up the alignment). After these changes, when I try to play it, a different error message pops up: "Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file."

Comment: This is actually my second attempt. My first attempt had code which attempted to be more precise (I used a byte array and assigned each byte individually, keeping track of endianness), and then wrote the array contents to a file. But this attempt gave the first error message I mentioned.

Comment: Are  you closing your streams correctly, before trying to play the file?

Comment: Or you can just use a [C# class that can create WAV for you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio).

Comment: The [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) project has a `WaveFileWriter` class, and many other helpful audio-related C# classes.

Comment: What is `WaveForm`? From what library?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The major problem is:**

[`BinaryWriter.Write(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) writes a string that **is prefixed with it's length** for `BinaryReader` to read it back. It is not intended to be used like your case. You need to write the bytes directly instead of using `BinaryWriter.Write(string)`.

**What you should do:**

Convert the string into bytes and then write the bytes directly.

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF");
binaryWriter.Write(data);
```

or make it one line:

```
binaryWriter.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));
```

---

There may also be other problems, like the integers you are writing may not be of the same size as required. You should check them carefully.

As for endianess, the link you put states that data are in little-endian and `BinaryWriter` uses little-endian, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: I fixed it. I think I needed to encode it in ASCII. Like I mentioned in a comment, I originally tried to use a byte array and deal with each byte individually (like if I were working in C). It was in this setup where I explicitly dealt with endianess (by shifting and isolating a byte and storing in the correct index). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way possible, you can simply change:

```
wr.Write("RIFF");
```

to:

```
wr.Write("RIFF".ToArray());
```

Writing a string in a binary file, it will include the length of the string so that it can be deserialized back into a string later. In this case you just want the four bytes to be written as four bytes, and converting it to a char array will do just that.

Answer (score 3):

I lack the proper WAV data, but try replacing the part of your code where you generate the header with this code (replace appropriately):

```
wr.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));
wr.Write(0);
wr.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVE"));
wr.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fmt "));
wr.Write(18 + (int)(numsamples * samplelength));
wr.Write((short)1); // Encoding
wr.Write((short)numchannels); // Channels
wr.Write((int)(samplerate)); // Sample rate
wr.Write((int)(samplerate * samplelength * numchannels)); // Average bytes per second
wr.Write((short)(samplelength * numchannels)); // block align
wr.Write((short)(8 * samplelength)); // bits per sample
wr.Write((short)(numsamples * samplelength)); // Extra size
wr.Write("data");
```

Comment: I get an error (the second one I mentioned above). It may be my data, but I'm pretty certain the correct number of bytes get written to the file, so at worst the result should be noise. I even changed the last line to be of the same format as the other strings.

Comment: I rearranged some things (I didn't understand your chunk sizes, for example, so I used mine), and the result actually worked! I don't know why though. Maybe the default for C# or Visual Studio isn't ASCII? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make my own recorder to use for Google's Voice Recognition (like a sort of desktop assistant). It took me a few hours to weed through the specifics of the WAV format too. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

@Alvin-wong answer works perfect. Just wanted to add another suggestion although a few more lines is:

```
binaryWriter.Write('R');
binaryWriter.Write('I');
binaryWriter.Write('F');
binaryWriter.Write('F');
```