# Record audio from Kinect via WAVEFORMATEX

Tags: c#, kinect, record, audio-streaming

I want to record the audio stream from Kinect and save it in my computer , so I refer the sample code here.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Audio-Fundamentals

Here is my partial code.

```
public static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
        {

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
            {
                int cbFormat = 18; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
                WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
                {
                    //wFormatTag = 0,
                    nChannels = 1,
                    nSamplesPerSec = 16000,
                    nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
                    nBlockAlign = 2,
                    wBitsPerSample = 16,
                    cbSize = 0
                };

                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
                {
                    //RIFF header               
                    WriteString(memStream, "data");
                    bw.Write(cbFormat);
                    WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
                    bw.Write(dataLength + cbFormat + 4); //File size - 8
                    WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
                    WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
                    bw.Write(cbFormat);

                    //WAVEFORMATEX
                    bw.Write(format.wFormatTag);
                    bw.Write(format.nChannels);
                    bw.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
                    bw.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
                    bw.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
                    bw.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);
                    bw.Write(format.cbSize);

                    //data header
                    WriteString(memStream, "data");
                    bw.Write(dataLength);
                    memStream.WriteTo(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

There's an error occur when in line "bw.Write(format.wFormatTag);" when I compile the code , but no error with other line in WAVEFORMATEX , I have add "Bass.Net" to my reference and using "Un4seen.Bass" , but I still can't fix it.

Comment: The error line says "Can not transfer to bool from  'Un4seen.Bass.WAVEFormatTag' "

Comment: According to http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/56c44e65-9b99-fa0d-d74a-3d9de3b01e89.htm `WAVEFormatTag` is an enum value. Cast it back to a number with the correct size. I don't know wether it should be a `short` or an `int` or whatever, you need to give it a try. So `bw.Write((short)format.wFormatTag);` could work.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works.

Comment: But I have another question , I want to set wFormatTag to 1 (to save as PCM data) , but the compiler only allows me to set it to 0. In this case , the  audio file I just record is broken.How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the compilation error? You should try to set the wFormatTag to the specific enum value, so e.g. writing 
`format,wFormatTag = Un4seen.Bass.WAVEFormatTag.PCM`, and *then* write it in the binary writer. You can also directly specifiy this when initializing your `format` object in the brace-initialization form.

Comment: Also i'm 100% sure now that it should be cast to a `short`, because the format in https://code.google.com/r/benjaminaautin-justadownload/source/browse/External/gccxml/share/gccxml-0.9/vc11/overrides/shared/mmreg.h?r=730c5ff598dc859822453a48e4d6805fe655d353#2107 is a two-byte value.

Comment: The error says "The int type can not transfer to 'Un4seen.Bass.WAVEFormatTag'.

Comment: But this error is solved by setting "wFormatTag" to "Un4seen.Bass.WAVEFormatTag.PCM". But the wav file I record is still broken.

Comment: This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659684/creating-a-wav-file-in-c-sharp) talks about how you should **not** write strings directly, but have them converted to a `byte[]` using ASCII encoding first. Maybe this gives you a hint?

Comment: Really thanks for helping. I'll continue working on it .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing several different SDKs. In the link you provided, the `WAVEFORMATEX` is defined as follows:

```
struct WAVEFORMATEX
{
    public ushort wFormatTag;
    public ushort nChannels;
    public uint nSamplesPerSec;
    public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
    public ushort nBlockAlign;
    public ushort wBitsPerSample;
    public ushort cbSize;
}
```

So, no enum values or `Un4seen.Bass` references. The function to write the header file is slighty different (only differs in the `wFormatTag` value):

```
/// <summary>
/// A bare bones WAV file header writer
/// </summary>        
static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
{
    //We need to use a memory stream because the BinaryWriter will close the underlying stream when it is closed
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
    {
        int cbFormat = 18; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
        WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
        {
            wFormatTag = 1,
            nChannels = 1,
            nSamplesPerSec = 16000,
            nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
            nBlockAlign = 2,
            wBitsPerSample = 16,
            cbSize = 0
        };

        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
        {
            //RIFF header
            WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
            bw.Write(dataLength + cbFormat + 4); //File size - 8
            WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
            WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
            bw.Write(cbFormat);

            //WAVEFORMATEX
            bw.Write(format.wFormatTag);
            bw.Write(format.nChannels);
            bw.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
            bw.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
            bw.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
            bw.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);
            bw.Write(format.cbSize);

            //data header
            WriteString(memStream, "data");
            bw.Write(dataLength);
            memStream.WriteTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

An `WriteString` also takes care of converting it to ASCII. I'm refering to the .zip file which is referenced in the presentation above ("Download the [Quickstart slides and samples](http://media.ch9.ms/coding4fun/KinectforWindowsSDKV1.zip)", KinectforWindowsSDKV1\6.Audio\AudioRecorder\AudioRecorder\MainWindow.xaml.cs)